# How do I access a routed parameter from inside a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is the route...

```
'panel-list' => array (
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array (
        'route'    => '/panel-list/:pageId[/:action]',
        'constraints' => array (
            'pageId' => '[a-z0-9_-]+'
        ),
        'defaults' => array (
            'action' => 'index',
            'controller' => 'PanelList',
            'site' => null
        ),
    ),
),
```

What do I need to put in here....

```
public function indexAction()
{
    echo ???????
}
```

to echo the pageId?

Comment: sorry about the mix up, posted a working answer now.

Comment: if you replace your `?????` with a pseudo-code and an comment indicating that's what you're looking for than I'll give you +1 for a perfectly phrased newbie question, although reading the docs would've answered it perfectly ;)

Comment: @SamuelHerzog At the time of the Q, there was really no doc. And unless they have done great work with the docs the two weeks I've been on holidays now it so far lagging behind (understandable as it's RC)

Comment: @Matsemann it wasn't at read-the-docs then if I recall correctly, but definitly in repository and definitly at the zend-framework homepage. I have been using ZF2 from beta2 and did find it in the (now-not-up-to-date-it-seems) docs at http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/index.html which are linked from http://framework.zend.com/zf2 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In beta5 of zf2 it changed to easier usage so you don't need to remember different syntax for every different type. I [cite](http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog/entry/Zend-Framework-2-0-0beta5-Released):

> New "Params" controller plugin. Allows retrieving query, post,
>         cookie, header, and route parameters. Usage is
>         $this->params()->fromQuery($name, $default).

So to get a parameter from the route, all you need to do is.

```
$param = $this->params()->fromRoute('pageId');
```

This can also be done with query ($_GET) and post ($_POST) etc. as the citation says.

```
$param = $this->params()->fromQuery('pageId');
// will match someurl?pageId=33

$param = $this->params()->fromPost('pageId');
// will match something with the name pageId from a form.

// You can also set a default value, if it's empty.
$param = $this->params()->fromRoute('key', 'defaultvalue');
```

Example:

```
$param = $this->params()->fromQuery('pageId', 55);
```

if the url is someurl?pageId=33 $param will hold the value 33.
if the url doesn't have ?pageId $param will hold the value 55

Comment: you'll get +1 as soon as you add the way without the plugin too! :)

Comment: @SamuelHerzog you mean as tomwrong's answer does? If so, I see no need duplicating his answer. If not, feel free to improve my answer through an edit. :)

Comment: yes, exactly, your answer should be complete by itself. There is nothing wrong to incorporate additions from other answers aswell. FAQs state so. A correct answer should be as meaningful as possible. This will guarantee long relevancy and lots of +1's of other people scanning it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('pageId')
```

Comment: yes tried that, thanks but it didn't work, I have reverse-engineered an answer but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Comment: I up-voted you because I think you have demonstrated a difference in ZF2

Comment: According to Matsemann yo are correct, however I could not get it to work.

Comment: @tomwrong I'm sorry, this will not be correct. See my answer.

Comment: please don't phrase your answer as an question ;)

Answer (score 2):

$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('pageId');